# How to find the definition of a method

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I've come across this file in Elementor: `wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php`, from line 2202 to 2211 is

```
protected function render() {}

/**
 * Render element in static mode.
 *
 * If not inherent will call the base render.
 */
protected function render_static() {
    $this->render();
}
```

As you can see in line 2202 this `render` method is empty. What I don't understand is if method `render` does nothing, then what does `$this->render()` do? Actually on the same file, the method `render` is called several times. I have also checked the parent object `Base_Object`, but it doesn't have this `render` method. I don't believe the `render` method is really empty, there must be some trick here that I need to learn. What is it?

[image]

Comment: Here’s [the commit](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/commit/e8f66c18ba226407c755e6782544285200d63f07) where it was introduced. Protected methods are still part of the [inheritance chain](https://3v4l.org/Y0WTV). I don’t know the specifics of this, but it is basically a no-op by default but a child class could override it if they wanted to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was misunderstood `debug_backtrace()`, which points me to `wp-content/plugins/elementor/includes/base/controls-stack.php`, but actually what gets exectued is the `render` method of a child object of class `Controls_stack`. It is indicated in the result of `debug_backtrace()` but I overlooked it.
[image]